# Parsing Environment Variables as Arguments in JNLP File

Tags: java, environment-variables, jnlp, java-web-start

I would like to know if there is a way of passing Windows environment variables as arguments in JNLP files?

I have a JNLP file in which I specify an argument that should be passed to the application's main method. If possible, I would like the argument to take the form `%USERPROFILE%/dir/file`. However, when I try to execute like this, webstart is taking userprofile as a literal value instead of replacing it with the environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of system property `user.dir` should be equivalent to `%USERPROFILE%` as an abstract file path.   Instead of specifying file as a JNLP program argument, obtain it as follows:

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "dir/file");
```

Comment: It seems this answer actually solves the problem the OP wanted to solve, but it doesn't answer the question the OP asked: How to use Windows environment variables as arguments in JNLP files. I would like an answer to the original question. There are cases where the environment variable isn't available to the application or is necessary as a JVM option.